# Proof explanation: Linear dependence of functionals.

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

Good night, i have a serious doubts with this proof. If someone can explain me the red parts i will be very grateful.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If $$\tag{1}\bigcap_{j\ne k}\ker f_j=\bigcap_j\ker f_j,$$ this means that 
$$
\bigcap_{j\ne k}\ker f_j=\ker f_k\cap\bigcap_{j\ne k}\ker f_j,
$$
so $\bigcap_{j\ne k}\ker f_j\subset\ker f_k$. This allows us to restart the argument of the Lemma and prove that $f_k$ is a linear combination of $\{f_j\}_{j\ne k}$ (we may need to recycle the argument down if the intersection still doesn't have the property, but with one functional less on each step, eventually condition $(1)$ fails, or we run out of functionals); then it is enough to prove the Lemma for $\{f_j\}_{j\ne k}$.

Your second question:
$$
f_k(x_k)=f_k\left(\frac{y_k}{f_k(y_k)}\right)=\frac{f_k(y_k)}{f_k(y_k)}=1.
$$

You have, by linearity
$$
f_j(y)=f_j\left(x-\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)x_k\right)
=f_j(x)-\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)f_j(x_k)=f_j(x_k)-f_j(x)f_j(x_j)=0,
$$
the second to last equality because $f_j(x_k)=0$ for $j\ne k$, and the last one because $f_j(x_j)=1$.

Comment: Thanks Martin, all is too clear and precise. One question, i don't understand very well this $\bigcap_{j\ne k}\ker f_j=\ker f_k\cap\bigcap_{j\ne k}\ker f_j,$ Sorry, can explain in more details this part...? sorry for that.

Comment: I'm contradicting $ \bigcap_{j\ne k}\ker f_j\ne\bigcap_j\ker f_j$, and writing $$\bigcap_j\ker f_j =\ker  f_k\cap \bigcap_{j\ne k}\ker f_j.$$

Comment: Yes, now i understand. Thanks Martin! Very thanks!!!